# how to load customer/group into Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price

Tags: price, customer, group

I have changed the price scheme based on customer group by percentage. So here I do the trick for the product

```
if ($group->getCode() == "High ST. Shops") {

    $percent = 100 - $_product->getHighstshopPerc();
    $percent = "0." . $percent;
    $srrp = $_product->getPrice() * $percent;
    echo "Your Price £" . number_format($srrp, 2, '.', '');
}
```

Now I need getPrice() to come from price.php already with my new scheme so it adds to cart correctly. I tried the code below but i cant get getCode() to give me customer group so I can calculate/override getPrice

```
public function getPrice($product)
{
//$groupId    = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
//$group      = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($groupId);

    //return $product->getData('price');
    //return $product->getTradePerc();
    //echo $product->getCode(); exit();
    if ($product->getCode() == "NOT LOGGED IN")
    return 1;
    else return 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you think about, to just create a cart rule to give customer groups discount?

Comment: will have a look into it, it may do what I need. Cheers